# How can I check if a TextArea string is within a tag?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am creating a rudimentary text editor with Python using TKinter. I have the basic menu functions and text area down, and I would like to have built in syntax highlighting (specifically for keywords in MS batch scripts).

How can I detect if a substring (e.g. a keyword) has already had a format text tag applied to it? Where do I start?

Comment: "How do I detect if a substring (e.g a keyword) has already had a format text tag applied to it? " **What does this mean**? What are "format text tags" in the context of your program? Do you already have code that can show formatted text? If so, how is the formatting applied? Please read [ask] and make it possible for us to understand the current state of the program. We don't know where to start, either, because we don't know where you are at the moment.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel TkInter text tags that you can apply to portions of text in the program are what I am referring to. The Text() widget automatically has this display functionality.

Comment: "TkInter text tags that you can apply to portions of text in the program are what I am referring to." Okay, but this would still be much better with a [mre].

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don’t know where to start with this sort of method, so I can’t give one. I could not find similar examples that fit my project online.

Comment: " I don’t know where to start with this sort of method, so I can’t give one." Please show enough of the existing code to understand what you are talking about. That is: some code that creates a text area and puts some formatted text in it - and then explain what you want to do with the existing formatted text and *why the text tags are making this difficult*. (I assume you would be able to solve the problem if the text area only had plain text in it, yes?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I detect if a substring (e.g. a keyword) has already had a format text tag applied to it? Where do I start?

You can use the `tag_names` method to get a list of all tags for a specific index in a text widget. If you have a range of characters, you can iterate over each character to get all of the tags in the range.

```
tags = text.tag_names("1.5")
```